# How to show long git output in separate buffer with less?

Tags: git, terminal

When I open `less`, it's in a separate buffer (maybe there's another term for that?): The scroll bar of my terminal disappears and I can scroll with the mouse wheel. Once `less` is closed, my bash session is restored.

If I have long output from git, it is automatically piped to `less` but in this case, it uses the same buffer as my session. The scroll bars of the terminal stay, scrolling with the mouse wheel scrolls the session and scrolling back and forth (with the keyboard) leaves everything that's ever shown in the terminal. The last thing can easily be shown by continuously hitting j and k. The first line will be repeated multiple times when scrolling the terminal buffer.

Other tools that use `less` work, e.g., long output from `psql` is shown with `less` in a separate buffer. How can I make git do the same?

Answer (score 2):

[git-config(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) says:

> core.pager
>
> The command that git will use to paginate output. Can be overridden with the GIT_PAGER environment variable. Note that git sets the LESS environment variable to FRSX if it is unset when it runs the pager.

The critical part is the `X` of the `LESS` variable. Consulting less' man page:

> -X or --no-init
>
> Disables sending the termcap initialization and deinitialization strings to the terminal.  This is sometimes desirable if the deinitialization string does something unnecessary, like clearing the screen.

So we need to disable that. Luckily, git-config(1) shows the solution:

> If you want to selectively override Git’s default setting for LESS, you can set core.pager to e.g.  less -+S. This will be passed to the shell by Git, which will translate the final command to LESS=FRSX less -+S.

Great, this is easier than setting the `LESS` variable ourselves if we are otherwise happy with the defaults. So the solution becomes:

```
git config --global core.pager 'less -+X -+F'
```

This re-enables termcap initialization which involves creating a new buffer. Unfortunately `F` also has do be disabled. It causes less to exit immediately if the output fits on the screen. Because the output is in another buffer, the command immediately returns without printing anything.